# Lightstreamer bug "Connection stalled for too long"

Tags: ios

I'm using Lighstreamer, I connect and wait for some time, I get error,

connection failure: **Lightstreamer** connection exception (reason: 'Connection stalled for too long').

After this error, It automatically connects again to same channel, However I didn't write code to connect again.

Can anyone guide, why is this error is coming and what is solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lightstreamer has a developer support forum, try also to reach them

Comment: Thanks. I do try there @Andrea